# Rails 7 - ActionCable - Broadcast do not render partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, broadcast, actioncable, ruby-on-rails-7

In controller RoomsController.rb

```
ActionCable.server.broadcast(
  "users_room_channel",
  {
    target: 'users_room_' + params[:room_id].to_s,
    partial: 'rooms/users_in_room',
    locals: { users_in_room: users_in_room_list(params[:room_id], params[:user_id]) }
  }
)
```

In users_room_channe.js

```
received(data) {

  console.log(data.partial) /// "string with partial name, not HTML code
  const targ = data.target
  const usersList = document.getElementById(targ)
  usersList.innerHTML = data.partial

 

}


UsersRoomChannel transmitting {"target"=>"users_room_1", 
"partial"=>"rooms/users_in_room", "locals"=>{"users_in_room"=> 
[{"id"=>1, "email"=>"chromebrowser@example.com", 
"created_at"=>"2023-04-28T10:54:10.649+02:00", 
"updated_at"=>"2023-05-01T19:49:13.298+02:00", "gender"=>nil, 
"username"=>"ChromeBrowser", "provider"=>nil, "uid... (via 
streamed from users_room_channel)
```

Why in view it display only string "rooms/users_in_room" and not partial HTML ?

```
<div id="users_room_1">rooms/users_in_room</div>
```